# How to parse a post request from Form to a REST Java/Jersey Webservice

Tags: java, http, jersey

In My Jersey web service, I have this method.

```
.../rest/services/save
```

How can I post/parse a long string coming from browser/form **without** showing it in the url.

```
String str = "user=mike&param2=value2&param3=value3&............................"
```

Comment: What did you try ? More details please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't show in the URL if you set the action on the form to POST instead of GET. You will accept @FormParams instead of query params on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser extension like POSTMAN:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Or use an HTML form.